# Count in class with static variable

Tags: java, class, counter

My code is suppose to create post it notes and write message, time of day and count the objects. (post1, post2, post3 etc)

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Post_it {
    private String note;
    static int number=0;

    private LocalTime ltime; 

    public Post_it(String note_, LocalTime time) {
        this.note = note_;
        this.ltime = time;
        number++;
    }
}
```

I try to print with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Post_it post1 = new Post_it("Text text text");
    Post_it post2 = new Post_it("Text Text");
    Post_it post3 = new Post_it("Text");

    System.out.println(Post_it.numbers);
}
```

But i cant print it, it complains of the Post_it.numbers. It´s possible to print post1.numbers but then i always get 0 even if i print post2.numbers.

Comment: You reinitialize the static property with every instantiation of an object. Don't!

Comment: What do you mean by it complains?

Comment: Your constructor expects two arguments. You're passing only one. **Read** the error messages you get. They mean something.

Comment: Could you please list the error you are receiving?

Comment: The static var is `number` not `numbers`, many errors in your code ;) Read all the comment to fix them

Comment: `Post_it.numbers` will give error because that class dosen't have a property named `numbers`, it should be `number`

Answer (score 0):

As `arkascha` already stated in the comments, you overwrite the counter each time you create a new object. But that's not the only error in your code.

You're getting the following error: `The constructor Post_it(String) is undefined` which means that the compiler wasn't able to find a constructor of `Post_it` with a `String` being the only argument.

You can fix this by adding a `LocalTime` to the constructor call:

```
new Post_it("Text text text", LocalTime.now())
```

Now to your counter - you have defined the Variable as `number` but access `Post_it.numbers` which is not quite right. It obviously has to be `Post_it.number`.

However, you can remove the static counter with a `List`, since it doesn't really have any use to define variables like you did. That's why things like a `List` or `Array` exist. I just modified your code a little bit, here is my approach:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Post_it
{
private String note;

private LocalTime time;

public Post_it(String note, LocalTime time)
{
    this.note = note;
    this.time = time;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Post_it> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    posts.add(new Post_it("Text text text", LocalTime.now()));
    posts.add(new Post_it("Text Text", LocalTime.now()));
    posts.add(new Post_it("Text", LocalTime.now()));
    System.out.println(posts.size());
}
```

}